# Unable to submit a form made through Infopath

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I have a strange problem and haven't been able to figure a workaround even after researching online for more than 2 weeks.

We use Office 365 Business Premium and through that i have created a Sharepoint Site to raise and approve Purchase Requests. The form was created using Infopath designer and the form contains certain calculations, repeating tables and approval matrices(looks-up to the sharepoint user list, matrix+workflow not configured as such).

The form is published to a particular site - xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/PurchaseOrder2/PurchaseRequistion/Forms/AllItems.aspx, where users do a new->Form to start entering the necessary details. There a lot of fields that have been marked "cannot be blank", the date fields work on a "=today" command and non-editable. The sub-total & grand total calculation has been coded on a button.

The problems currently is below:

When data is submitted, the error "The form cannot be submitted because of an error" occurs. the error details gives me "The form cannot be submitted to the specified SharePoint list or document library. The SharePoint location may be read-only or you may not have permissions to access it.An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.Log ID:5567

im also unable to submit a simple form in the same library with no data entry, get the same error. the issue also occurs when i try to submit the form in another library.

I currently have global administrator access and other users have edit access. Request all your input and feedback on this.

Thanks!

**Edit on 12-11-19**

Hello everyone,

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What are the item level permissions of the list?

Answer (score 0):

Infopath is deprecated; your best bet for path-forward sustainability is to use PowerApps for Purchase Requests.  You can still connect to your SharePoint source lists.  There are a number of well-designed templates via PowerApps to help shape ideas or give you a foundation to build upon.  Good luck.

Comment: thanks! but we are looking at continuing with Infopath for now